# React Query doesn't seem to be caching

Tags: reactjs, caching, react-query

I was following an example I saw on YouTube for using [React Query](https://react-query.tanstack.com/), but I can't seem to get the caching to work as expected. In my app the data is fetched every time. Not sure if I'm missing something obvious. Here is my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-faraday-nhmlb?file=/src/App.js

When clicking the Planets and People buttons, I can see network requests being made each time I flip back and forth. I would expect to see it make a request for each set of data once at least for some time while the cache is still active.

Anyone know what might be wrong?

Answer (score 35):

From [Important Defaults](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/important-defaults) section:

> Query instances via `useQuery` or `useInfiniteQuery` by default **consider
> cached data as stale.**

> Stale queries are refetched automatically in the background when:
>
> - New instances of the query mount

By default, when a query is successfully fetched, it's considered stale immediately, that's why your data is refetched every time you change the tab. You can set a longer `staleTime` (default to `0`) if you don't want the aggressive refetching behavior:

```js
const { isLoading, error, data } = useQuery("planets", fetchPlanets, {
  staleTime: 10000, // only eligible to refetch after 10 seconds
});
```

Optionally, you can set `staleTime` globally for all queries during QueryClient instantiation, like so:

```js
const queryClient = new QueryClient({
    defaultOptions: { queries: { staleTime: 10000 }}
});
```

There is another error in your code not very related to `react-query`, in this code of yours below:

```js
function App() {
  const [page, setPage] = useState("planets");

  const queryClient = new QueryClient();

  const pageSetter = (page) => {
    setPage(page);
  };

  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Star Wars Info</h1>
        <Navbar setPage={pageSetter} />
        <div className="content">
          {page === "planets" ? <Planets /> : <People />}
        </div>
      </div>
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
}
```

Every time the user clicks the buttons to display different data, the whole component gets re-render, a new instance of `queryClient` is created and passed to `QueryClientProvider`,  resetting any internal state of the client cache. You should decouple your component to avoid unnecessary re-render like this:

```js
function Content() {
  const [page, setPage] = useState("planets");
  const pageSetter = (page) => {
    setPage(page);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Star Wars Info</h1>
      <Navbar setPage={pageSetter} />
      <div className="content">
        {page === "planets" ? <Planets /> : <People />}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

// top level component, should not get re-rendered
function App() {
  const queryClient = new QueryClient();

  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <Content />
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 67040687/react-query-doesnt-seem-to-be-caching]

Answer (score 17):

You are creating a new QueryClient inside the app component, so when it re-renders, you basically throw away the cache. Create the  `new QueryClient ()` outside of the app like in the example.

Also, please note that you will then still see network requests, because react-query will do background refetches with the default staleTime of 0 when a component mounts. You can set it to something higher if you don’t want that.

Comment: TkDodo to the rescue. This is the whole answer imo.

Comment: Yeah i had same issue - moved out "const queryClient = new QueryClient();" of App.js

Comment: Bro, you totally saved me, after a month of finding the bug, it was that simple.